SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number, fetch data from API
i faced this error when i build API, i want to fetch data that can filter based on 2 category (cpNumber or partNumber).
this is result from postman, status code 500
{"error":"Database error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"}

this is my API, i've tried to change to bindParam instead of bindValue, and change to PARAM_STR, but itsn't work.
function searchItems($pdo, $searchTerm, $page = 1, $limit = 10) {
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, oka, lot, part_no, qty_lot, tgl_trn, no_ctplan, idbarang, no_bpm, tgl_bpm, rev, ket_wi, keterangan 
                           FROM wi_trn
                           WHERE part_no LIKE :searchTerm OR no_ctplan LIKE :searchTerm
                           LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");

    $searchTermLike = "%$searchTerm%";
    $stmt->bindValue(':searchTerm', $searchTermLike, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

try {
    // Inisialisasi koneksi PDO
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

    // Mengambil parameter dari request (contoh menggunakan GET parameter 'q' dan 'page')
    $searchTerm = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '';
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;

    // Memanggil fungsi pencarian
    $items = searchItems($pdo, $searchTerm, $page);

    // Menghitung total item (tidak efisien, disarankan menggunakan COUNT() dalam query terpisah)
    $totalItems = count($items);

    // Menyiapkan respons JSON
    $response = [
        'status' => 'ok',
        'currentPage' => $page,
        'totalItems' => $totalItems,
        'items' => $items
    ];

    // Mengirim respons JSON
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Tangani kesalahan PDO
    http_response_code(500); // Set HTTP response code 500 untuk server error
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
}
?>

thanks a lot.

Try with :searchTerm1 and :searchTerm2 instead of using :searchTerm twice in the query.
